# Trying to add substrings from newLines in a large file to a list

Tags: java

I downloaded my extended listening history from Spotify and I am trying to make a program to turn the data into a list of artists without doubles I can easily make sense of. The file is rather huge because it has data on every stream I have done since 2016 (307790 lines of text in total). This is what 2 lines of the file looks like:

```
{"ts":"2016-10-30T18:12:51Z","username":"edgymemes69endmylifepls","platform":"Android OS 6.0.1 API 23 (HTC, 2PQ93)","ms_played":0,"conn_country":"US","ip_addr_decrypted":"68.199.250.233","user_agent_decrypted":"unknown","master_metadata_track_name":"Devil's Daughter (Holy War)","master_metadata_album_artist_name":"Ozzy Osbourne","master_metadata_album_album_name":"No Rest for the Wicked (Expanded Edition)","spotify_track_uri":"spotify:track:0pieqCWDpThDCd7gSkzx9w","episode_name":null,"episode_show_name":null,"spotify_episode_uri":null,"reason_start":"fwdbtn","reason_end":"fwdbtn","shuffle":true,"skipped":null,"offline":false,"offline_timestamp":0,"incognito_mode":false},

{"ts":"2021-03-26T18:15:15Z","username":"edgymemes69endmylifepls","platform":"Android OS 11 API 30 (samsung, SM-F700U1)","ms_played":254120,"conn_country":"US","ip_addr_decrypted":"67.82.66.3","user_agent_decrypted":"unknown","master_metadata_track_name":"Opportunist","master_metadata_album_artist_name":"Sworn In","master_metadata_album_album_name":"Start/End","spotify_track_uri":"spotify:track:3tA4jL0JFwFZRK9Q1WcfSZ","episode_name":null,"episode_show_name":null,"spotify_episode_uri":null,"reason_start":"fwdbtn","reason_end":"trackdone","shuffle":true,"skipped":null,"offline":false,"offline_timestamp":1616782259928,"incognito_mode":false},
```

It is formatted in the actual text file so that each stream is on its own line. NetBeans is telling me the exception is happening at line 19 and it only fails when I am looking for a substring bounded by the indexOf function. My code is below. I have no idea why this isn't working, any ideas?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        File dat = new File("SpotifyListeningData.txt");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner swag = null;
        
        try {
            swag = new Scanner(dat);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("pranked");
        }
        
        while (swag.hasNextLine())
            if (swag.nextLine().length() > 1)
                if (list.contains(swag.nextLine().substring(swag.nextLine().indexOf("artist_name"), swag.nextLine().indexOf("master_metadata_album_album"))))
                    System.out.print("");
                else
                    try {list.add(swag.nextLine().substring(swag.nextLine().indexOf("artist_name"), swag.nextLine().indexOf("master_metadata_album_album")));}
                    catch(Exception e) {}
        
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read this [Guideline on formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: You should log the line that fails. My guess is that maybe one key is missing or maybe they are in a different order than you thnk

Comment: I notice you're calling `swag.nextLine()` over and over in the same line. This will keep reading a new line for every time it's called (four times per loop) - did you mean to assign the value of `swag.nextLine()` to a variable at the beginning of each loop iteration, and use that for all subsequent references?

Comment: This looks like JSON. You should not parse JSON yourself, but let a library do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find a JSON parser you like.
2. Create a class that with the fields you care about marked up to the parsers specs.
3. Read the file into a collection of objects. Most parsers will stream the contents so you're not string a massive string.
4. You can then load the data into objects and store that as you see fit.  For your purposes, a TreeSet is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will throw a lot of exceptions only because you don't use **braces**. Please do use braces in each blocks, whether it is `if`, `else`, `loops`, whatever. It's a good practice and prevent unnecessary bugs.

However, everytime `scanner.nextLine()` is called, it reads the next line from the file, so you need to avoid using that in this way.

The best way to deal with this is to write a class containing the fields same as the `json` in each line of the file. And map the `json` to the class and get desired field value from that.

Your way is too much risky and dependent on structure of the data, even on whitespaces. However, I fixed some lines in your code and this will work for your purpose, although I actually don't prefer operating string in this way.

```
while (swag.hasNextLine()) {
    String swagNextLine = swag.nextLine();
    if (swagNextLine.length() > 1) {
        String toBeAdded = swagNextLine.substring(swagNextLine.indexOf("artist_name") + "artist_name".length() + 2
                , swagNextLine.indexOf("master_metadata_album_album") - 2);
        if (list.contains(toBeAdded)) {
            System.out.print("Match");
        } else {
            try {
                list.add(toBeAdded);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Add to list failed");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```